# Difference between type and class in c++?

Tags: c++, class

I notice that our home doesn't have this *easy* question, so I'll post it.

One says type is built-in type, such as int, long, char, etc, while class is a user-defined class.
Is it right?

Comment: int etc. are builtin types, yes. Classes are user-defined, yes. But there are more user-defined things than classes (typedef, enums, etc.etc.)

Comment: _“One says type is built-in type, such as int, long, char, etc, while class is a user-defined class.”_ It is definitely not correct as it’s a [circular definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_definition).

Comment: Read the first sentence in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_classes

Answer (score 5):

> Is it right?

No. From the C++ standard's working draft, [we know that](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#1) (emphasis mine):

> A class **is** a type.

In particular, it is a *compound type*.
On the other side, `char`, `int` and so on are considered *fundamental types*.

See [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types) for further details about types.

Answer (score 1):

`Type` is something which defines the memory footprint of variable. For e.g :- when I declare a variable as `int`, compiler allocates fixed amount of memory which may OR may not be different from other types `float`, `double` etc.

Similarly, a `class` is blue print of objects. It defines the layout of the object in memory. And hence class is also a type.

Comment: "Type" also defines the operations that are allowed on that chunk of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Type is more like name of your caste, For example: The object is of type int or employee(where employee is a class)

Class is telling you the structure of user defined type. call it blue print and what ever is convenient to you.

You can also say the class name is type.

Comment: class is blue print of an object. It is like your house plan which you get approved from municipal authorities.

an instance of class is object and in the context of Data Types , same is called Type.

So, i would say it is the context which decided the word to use but both are same.